# Creating a CSV file in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to create a CSV file from a stored procedure?

I need to create a CSV file with data from a table, that is retrieved in a stored procedure

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work on a simple Stored Procedure, replace "YourDatabase.dbo.YourSproc"

```
DECLARE @string AS NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT    @string = 'BCP "exec YourDatabase.dbo.YourSproc" QUERYOUT c:\data.csv -c -T -t'

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @string
```

Comment: Works good, but you have to add a comma after the '-t'. Otherwise it will just put all of the columns in the same row in excel.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I really see this possible is, in the stored procedure, have a call to `xp_cmdshell` to execute `bcp` with the parameters you are looking for.  Not sure of any other way to do that.