# How to send the output of a stored procedure running on a linked server into a csv file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query running on my local PC:

```
USE [MyDatabase]

EXEC [xxx.yyy.10.23].[Emp_LIVE].[dbo].[procBIInterfaceEmployee]
```

`[xxx.yyy.10.23]` is a linked server. When I execute this T-SQL code, it runs fine and returns the expected results.

I would like to wrap the above codes into a new T-SQL query that would write the results into a csv file on my local PC.

Searching StackOverflow.com for a solution, I have landed on these 2 questions:

1. [Creating a CSV file in a SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793567/creating-a-csv-file-in-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)
2. [How to write using BCP to a remote SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655247/how-to-write-using-bcp-to-a-remote-sql-server)

So, I came up with the following (based on the answers from the above 2 questions):

```
DECLARE @string AS NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @string = 'BCP "exec [xxx.yyy.10.23].[Emp_LIVE].[dbo].[procBIInterfaceEmployee]" QUERYOUT c:\testfolder\empdata.csv -c -T -t, -S"xxx.yyy.10.27\BI-SQL"'

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @string
```

`xxx.yyy.10.27\BI-SQL` is the remote server where `[MyDatabase]` is hosted. `BI-SQL` is the instance of that server.

Running my new set of code, I get the following errors:

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
>   NULL

How do I move forward with this?

Comment: You are mixing your local side and server side. Anyway xp_cmdshell could be dangerous and running arbitrary command on OS is almost never a good idea. I suggest to use SSIS package

Comment: "You are mixing your local side and server side..." Is this the issue for this not working?

Comment: Does your service account (or logged-in) user has rights to post to the remote server?

Comment: @Faisal Mehboob No, if you mean server [xxx.yyy.10.23]

Comment: You need to grant your sa access to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Insert your sp result in a local table
2. and then export from your local table.

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
```

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[procBIInterfaceEmployee](
--whats in the table
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[procBIInterfaceEmployee]
EXEC [xxx.yyy.10.23].[Emp_LIVE].[dbo].[procBIInterfaceEmployee]

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "[MyDatabase].[dbo].[procBIInterfaceEmployee]" OUT c:\testfolder\empdata.csv -c -T -t, -S"LOCALHOST" '

Note: if you have instance, you will need to do -S"LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS"

See the bcp page for all parameters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility